# R: "load" from ascii .rd character vector

Tags: php, r

In R, is it possible to "load" an R data object as its ascii character vector representation?

```
### e.g.,

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, pi)

y <- list("a"=5, "b"="hello")

save(x, y, file=file.path("~", "Desktop", "xtest.rd"), ascii=TRUE)

xx <- readLines(file.path("~", "Desktop", "xtest.rd"))
xx

### this is the .rd file as an ascii character vector
### can we "load" xx to assign x and y (the contents of the .rd file)
### into the current environment ?
```

I imagine this can be done with pipe(), but I'm wondering if there might be a "best way".
This is for Mac and Linux.
Thank you!

Comment: read `?save`and see you already named the function `load`. i.e: `load(file=file.path("~", "Desktop", "xtest.rd"))`

Comment: Was the PHP tag an accident, or am I missing something?

Comment: Good.  An important example of why this functionality would be valuable: Suppose we're in a PHP session.  PHP reads xtest.rd as a ascii text file.  We can then pass this character string to an R session.  Currently we deal with this using JSONs and/or XML, but packing and unpacking the objects can be a major hassle.